# Cómo controlar con SQL que no te coja valores vacíos de una tabla

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy desarrollando un sistema de logs con PHP/MySQL/SQL. Entenderemos mejor esta duda con algo de código:

```
foreach ($EANsNoCoinciden as $key => $value) {
    $sqlproveedor="UPDATE articulos_nuevos_definitiva SET `PROVEEDOR`= (SELECT `proveedor` FROM proveedores WHERE `ean`=".$value[0].") WHERE `ean`=".$value[0];
    $resultadoproveedor=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sqlproveedor);
    if($resultadoproveedor){
        echo "El artículo con el valor"." ".($value[0])." "."actualizó correctamente el valor de su campo PROVEEDOR. <br>";

        $sql="UPDATE `logs_articulos_api_csv` SET `PROVEEDOR_articulos_nuevos_definitiva`='Correcto' WHERE `id`=$idfinal";
        $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);
    }else{
        echo "El artículo con el valor"." ".($value[0])." "."tuvo errores en la actualización de su campo PROVEEDOR. <br>";
        echo "Error: ".$sql. "<br>" .mysqli_error($conWebService)."<br>";

        $sql="UPDATE `logs_articulos_api_csv` SET `PROVEEDOR_articulos_nuevos_definitiva`='Ha habido errores al actualizar el campo PROVEEDOR de articulos_nuevos_definitiva desde la tabla proveedores' WHERE `id`=$idfinal";
        $resultado=mysqli_query($conWebService, $sql);
    }
}
```

A ver, con este código básicamente lo que quiero es ir cogiendo de la tabla `proveedores` aquellos campos que me interesan (en este caso `PROVEEDOR`) para ir actualizándolo en la tabla `articulos_nuevos_definitiva` dónde hay registros con otros campos rellenos pero no este en concreto. El problema que tengo es que este código es funcional (funciona perfectamente) pero no el sistema de logs. Me explico. De nuevo, se entenderá mejor con algo de código:

```
El artículo con el valor 3EB967LU tuvo errores en la actualización de su campo REFERENCIA PROVEEDOR.
Unknown column '3EB967LU' in 'where clause'
```

Esto es lo que me imprime en pantalla. Y ello se debe a que dicho artículo no existe en esa tabla (muchos existen, pero muchos otros no). ¿Cómo puedo controlarlo de forma que no de error? Porque el problema es que aunque este código me hace las actualizaciones bien, en el sistema de logs me da error porque claro, hay sentencias SQL que dan error, pero no por un problema con el código, sino con los datos, que si no hay datos, no puede ejecutar la sentencia bien. Muchas gracias, saludos.

ACTUALIZACIÓN:

A ver, que no es que coja datos de una tabla vacía, si no que en la tabla de proveedores hay muchos artículos (que se identifican por el `ean`) y habrá algunos que sí estén y otros que no.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN CON DATOS DE PRUEBA.**

*Tabla articulos_nuevos_definitiva.*

ean VARCHAR 20
PROVEEDOR VARCHAR 50
REFERENCIA PROVEEDOR VARCHAR 50

*Tabla proveedores*

proveedor VARCHAR 50
ean char 13
marca VARCHAR 50

*Ejemplo de datos de la tabla articulos_nuevos_definitiva*

ean 1234567890123
PROVEEDOR
REFERENCIA PROVEEDOR

ean 1111122222333
PROVEEDOR
REFERENCIA PROVEEDOR

*Ejemplo de datos de la tabla proveedores*

proveedor teka
ean 1234567890123
marca teka

proveedor arca
ean 972654321786
marca arca

*Explicación*

Cómo podéis observar, en la tabla `articulos_nuevos_definitiva` me faltan campos por rellenar, que sí que están rellenos en la tabla `proveedores`. De ahí ese `UPDATE`, para actualizar los registros de la tabla `articulos_nuevos_definitiva`. Eso sí... ¿Qué ocurre cuándo tengo un registro identificado por su `ean` en la tabla `articulos_nuevos_definitiva` pero no en la tabla `proveedores`? (un producto puede no ser de ningún proveedor, porque no esté aún la información de dicho proveedor en el sistema informático). En ese momento, al hacer la sentencia SQL (los `ean` se obtienen recorriendo el array `$EANsNoCoinciden`, lo que ocurre es que no se encuentra el `ean` en la tabla `proveedores` y salta el error en el log). Pero claro, no es un error de que el programa no funcione, sino simplemente de que faltan datos. Como el sistema de logs ha de ser fiable, mi pregunta es cómo controlar mediante SQL que cuando encuentre un dato vacío que quiere recoger, pues que se lo salte y no dé el error. Gracias, saludos.

*Actualización*

Sé que tiene que ser algo de este estilo:

```
UPDATE `articulos_nuevos_definitiva` 
SET `REFERENCIA PROVEEDOR`= 
(SELECT `proveedor` FROM proveedores WHERE `ean`="3EB967LU" AND `ean`="3EB967LU"<>) 
WHERE `ean`="3EB967LU"
```

pero me da error y no me aclaro con la sintaxis. Básicamente con `<>` lo que le quiero decir es que sólo me coja ese ean y me haga la consulta si el ean existe y no está vacío. A ver si alguien sabe cómo se puede hacer de forma correcta, gracias.

*ACTUALIZACIÓN*

Creo que puede ser esta consulta, pero la verdad es que no le veo el fallo ahora mismo. En MYSQL me ejecuta sin error, pero en PHP me falla, me lo marca el VSCode como error, y no le veo el fallo:

```
$sqlproveedor="UPDATE articulos_nuevos_definitiva SET `PROVEEDOR`= (SELECT `proveedor` FROM `proveedores` WHERE `ean`=".'$value[0]'.<>''") WHERE `ean`=".$value[0];
```

A ver si alguien le ve el fallo. Me dice que `unexpected <>. T_IS_NOT_EQUAL`.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE columna IS NOT NULL;` Algo así es lo que buscas ??

Comment: ¿Cómo le meterías eso al código SQL desde PHP? ```"UPDATE articulos_nuevos_definitiva SET `PROVEEDOR`= (SELECT `proveedor` FROM proveedores WHERE `ean`=".$value[0].") WHERE `ean`=".$value[0];``` ¿? ```"UPDATE articulos_nuevos_definitiva SET `PROVEEDOR`= (SELECT `proveedor` IS NOT NULL FROM proveedores WHERE `ean`=".$value[0].") WHERE `ean`=".$value[0];``` o algo así ¿? Es que me suena bastante raro y no sé bien cómo meterlo.

Comment: Tu quieres todos los datos, excepto los que no son nulos cierto ?

Comment: El error que mostras no esta en el codigo que mostras.. y el error en tu programa es raro... tenes una columna que se llama 3EB967LU????

Comment: @Excorpion todos los datos excepto los que están vacíos (nulos no va a haber). Y el error ese viene al coger de otro campo (REFERENCIA PROVEEDOR) pero vamos, que es el mismo problema que con el campo PROVEEDOR. 3EB967LU no es un campo, es uno de los valores de la tabla proveedores que selecciono para actualizar en la tabla articulos_nuevos_definitiva.

Comment: Un sql no deberia dar error y menos en el log, porque no hay datos. Como podes seleccionar valores de una tabla, si no hay datos? algo no esta bien en esto.. tal vez quieras explicar mejor que pasa?

Comment: Lo he explicado mejor en la actualización. En la tabla de proveedores hay muchos artículos, y yo tengo que seleccionar unos determinados campos para llevármelos a la tabla artículos_nuevos_definitiva. ¿Qué ocurre? Que hay artículos que no están en la tabla de proveedores, pero otros muchos sí. ¿Lo entiendes mejor ahora?

Comment: Añadiendo a lo que ampliaste, ejemplos con datos de prueba, se va a entender mejor.

Comment: Actualizado con datos de prueba.

Comment: sigo sin entender mucho como puede ser que algo tenga datos en una tabla, no tenga datos en la otra, y sin embargo tu programa te deje seleccionarlo.. Mas alla de eso, estas tratando de hacer algo en una sola query, que es mucho mas simple hacer en 2, porque no se puede en una. Simplemente verifica que proveedor no sea null, y si lo es, no hagas nada, y si no lo es, hace los cambios que queres...

Comment: A ver, es simple. Yo recorro un array con eans, y se lo meto a la sql porque el array lo voy recorriendo con un bucle. Si por casualidad coje un ean que no está en la otra tabla... ¿Por qué no me va a dejar el programa hacer la consulta? Si me deja, el problema que me da error claro, y no porque el programa esté mal, si no porque hay datos que faltan.

Comment: y fui claro... no lo vas a poder resolver con un solo sql. Necesitas dos. Uno que testee si el dato existe o no, y otro que haga lo que corresponda segun lo anterior...

Comment: Vale. ¿Cómo lo harías basándote en la sql con PHP que puse anteriormente? Porque tengo un lío tremendo y no sabría ahora mismo como hacerlo.

Comment: yo no se php.. pero ya te dije.. haces una query, te fijas si devuelve un prov que no sea null.. y si no es null, haces el update al log que queres.. igual, tener un log, y no guardar los errores, tambien es muy raro....

Comment: Es que en MySQL no es lo mismo tener un dato vacío que tener un dato que sea NULL. Y no se trata de no guardar los errores, se trata de guardar errores que sean errores, no errores porque falta un dato (que no es un fallo del programa, sino un fallo humano).

Comment: y un fallo humano, no es un error peor que uno de sistemas? si no, quien se va a dar cuenta de ese fallo humano... y cuando hagas un query y no devuelvan registros, la cuenta de registros deberia dar cero...

Comment: Comprendo tu opinión, pero me han pedido que lo haga así.

Answer (score 1):

Olvidaste poner las comillas simples (`) al rededor de: $value[0] en la consulta SQL, de otro modo, el gestor pensará que el id de PROVEEDOR que estas ingresando es otro nombre de una columna, he aqui un ejemplo de como lo ve el compilador:

```
where `ean` = 3EB967LU    -- Incorrecto
where `ean` = `3EB967LU`  -- Correcto
```

Prueba a hacerlo con esta consulta

```
$sqlproveedor="UPDATE articulos_nuevos_definitiva SET `PROVEEDOR`= (SELECT `proveedor` FROM proveedores WHERE `ean`="."`".$value[0]."`".") WHERE `ean`="."`".$value[0]."`";
```

Saludos ;)

Comment: ```Error: UPDATE `logs_articulos_api_csv` SET `PROVEEDOR_articulos_nuevos_definitiva`='Ha habido errores al actualizar el campo PROVEEDOR de articulos_nuevos_definitiva desde la tabla proveedores' WHERE `id`=7
Unknown column 'HB578G0S00' in 'where clause'```

Como puedes ver, sigue dando error.

Comment: Nuevamente olvidaste poner las comillas al rededor de: $idfinal. Esta vez en la linea 13 del primer código que describiste. Prueba con esta:  `$sql="UPDATE 'logs_articulos_api_csv' SET 'PROVEEDOR_articulos_nuevos_definitiva'='Ha habido errores al actualizar el campo PROVEEDOR de articulos_nuevos_definitiva desde la tabla proveedores' WHERE 'id'='".$idfinal."'";`

Comment: Ten en cuenta que la consulta que quiero modificar, que en MySQL poniéndole yo el valor no me da error pero sí en PHP (estaré haciendo algo mal) es la siguiente: ```$sqlproveedor="UPDATE articulos_nuevos_definitiva SET `REFERENCIA PROVEEDOR`= (SELECT `proveedor` FROM proveedores WHERE `ean`='$value[0]'<>' ') WHERE `ean`=".$value[0];``` es decir, necesito que sólo coja el ```proveedor``` si es distinto de 0, no sé si está es la mejor forma de ponerlo o no.

Comment: En ese caso, si la columna `proveedor` es de tipo `INT`, puedes reemplazarlo por: `"WHERE ean = ".$value[0]."AND ean NOT LIKE 0"`, de modo que si encuentra el valor pero este es igual a 0, retornará un resultado vacío.

Comment: La columna proveedor es de tipo ```VARCHAR```. He probado ```NOT LIKE ' '```, ```IS NOT NULL``` pero sigue sin arrojarme el resultado que necesito.

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente he optado por una solución en PHP. He creado un array que cogía (con un `SELECT`) sólo los ean que coincidían entre ambas tablas y luego ya he ejecutado los `UPDATE` sin problema.

Comment: Esto parece un comentario mas que una respuesta.. mira por favor [answer]